# Adding series dynamically in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```
(function($){
  $(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
          useUTC: false
        }
      });
      var i=0;
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          type: 'spline',
          renderTo: 'container',
          animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
          marginRight: 10,
          events: {
            load: function() {
              // set up the updating of the chart each second
              var series = this.series[0];
              setInterval(function() {
                var Name = new Array();
                Name[0] = "Random data";
                Name[1] = "Volvo";
                var length=chart.series.length;
                var flag=0;
                var index=0;
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.random();
                for (var k=0;k<Name.length;k++) {
                  for(var j=0;j<chart.series.length;j++) {
                    if(chart.series[j].name==Name[k]) {
                      flag=1;
                      index=j;
                      x = (new Date()).getTime();
                      y = Math.random();
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                  if(flag==1) {
                    chart.series[index].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    flag=0;
                  } else {
                    chart.addSeries({name: '' + Name[k] + '', data: [] });
                    chart.series[length].addPoint([x, y+1], true);
                    length=length+1;
                  }
                }
              }, 1000);
            }
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Value'
          },
          plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
          }]
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
              Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
              Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Random data',
          data: (function() {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;
            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
              data.push({
                x: time + i * 1000,
                y: Math.random()
              });
            }
            return data;
          })()
        }]
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I am able to add series and add point in charts but the series that I add after initialization, which is "volvo", is not drawing lines between its points. What might be the problem?

And is there any other way of comparing arrays and adding points without a for-loop? Because I can get millions of series at times and I don't want to be looping over arrays to check if it exists or not. So is there any efficient way of finding wheteher a list already exists, and if it does what is its index?

here is its fiddle: www.jsfiddle.net/2jYLz/

Answer (score 0):

It is related with fact that you have enabled shifting in addPoint() when you add new serie. In other words, shifting remove first point and add new in the end of serie. So when you have one point it caused your scenario. So you need to disable shipfing, and when lenght of series.data achieve i.e 10 points, shifting should be enabled.